# How to determine the nullity of P(A)

Tags: linear-algebra

I am stuck on the following problem :

Let $V$ be a vector space of all $2 \times 2$ matrices . Let $A$ be any $2 \times 2$ matrix . $B$ is another known matrix where $B=\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
2 &1 \\ 
0 &3 
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$. $P(A)=AB-BA$ is any polynomial. Then determine the nullity of P(A).

I have spent some time with this problem and find that nullity of $P(A)$ is $0$. But, I am not sure about the result. Can 
someone explain it in details. Thanks and regards to all.

Comment: "$P(A)=AB-BA$ is any polynomial".  What exactly do you mean by this?

Comment: Certainly, the nullity of $P$ is at least $1$ since $P(B) = 0$

Comment: I am not sure what It meant. It would be easier to think that I have to determine the nullity of $AB-BA.$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom   Can you please give explanation about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $P$ is a linear transformation and the nullity of $P$ is  the dimension of the set of matrices $A$ which commutes with $B$. Let 
$$A=\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
x &y \\ 
z &t 
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$$
and solve the four equations given by the equality
$$AB=BA$$

Comment: No since these matrices are linearly independent then the nullity is $2$.

Comment: Using your hint,I get $z=0,x+y=t.$ Now, If I take $x=c,y=d$ then the matrix takes the form $A=c\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
1 &0 \\ 
0 &1 
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)+d\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
0 &1 \\ 
0 &1 
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$ and since the matrices $\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
1 &0 \\ 
0 &1 
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr),\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
0 &1 \\ 
0 &1 
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$ are linearly independent,nullity of $P(A)$ is $2$. Am I right,sir?

Comment: thanks a lot sir.It is crystal clear now.

Comment: You're welcome.